# WPF - DockPanel Question

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am very new to WPF and am trying to understand the DockPanel control. I am building a Window, and am using a DockPanel in order to dock controls the way I want them. However, is it possible to dock the DockPanel itself, say to the top of the Window? I can't seem to find a way to do this. Ideally I would like to have the DockPanel dock itself to the top of my Window so that when the Window is resized, it grows or shrinks as the window is resized horizontally.

The problem is I cannot find a Doc property on the DockPanel itself. Is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to place it within another DockPanel if you wished to dock it.

That being said, my experience has been that when a layout gets to the level of complexity you are describing, it's often better to switch to using a Grid control.  This gives you a huge amount of control over layout, and makes having dynamically growing rows/columns (with fixed size portions between) easy.

---

Edit in response to comments:

You can use a Grid that scales as needed.  For example, by using star syntax, you can have a grid where the top row is always 1/3rd of the window size, and the bottom row is 2/3rds, like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

For details on options for sizing, see [GridLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx).  You can use "Auto" (fit to contents), "*" to scale based on space, or a fixed height (put in a number).

Comment: @Reed - I've made this sound much more complex than it really is. Let me try to simplify by asking a question. Say you wanted to put just a single tab control in a window and have it docked to the top of the window so that it expands or contracts horizontally as the user resizes the window horizontally. How would you do it?

Comment: @Randy: I'd just use a Grid with 2 rows.  It'll "just work" that way by default.  That being said, I've found that I rarely use DockPanel, since Grid tends to be much more flexible once you figure it out...

Comment: @Reed - I think we're getting close! One more question. If I use a grid, when the user expands or shrinks the window, how do I get the grid to expand or shrink with it?

Comment: @Randy: By default, it will automatically fill the space of it's parent.  If you want the row to expand/shink, set the height appropriately.  I'll edit to demonstrate...

Comment: @Reed - Thank you. That is a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this what you want but I have a `DockPanel` with a `Menu`.  When I resize the window the menu resizes with it.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Height="50" Margin="0" Name="MenuDockPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">

    <Menu Height="23" Name="MenuPanel" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
    </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
<Grid>
```

Hope this helps